# Function is returning value before running inner actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

Using SharePoint's `PreSaveAction()` that fires when the Save button is clicked, I am trying to run checks and manipulate fields before the form is saved. If `PreSaveAction()` returns `true`, the form will be saved and closed.

```
function PreSaveAction() {
  var options = {
    "url": "https://example.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    }
  }

  $.ajax(options).done(function (response) {
    var actualHours = response.d.results[0].ActualHours
    var personalHours = $("input[title$='Personal Hours']").val();
    var regex = /^\d*\.?\d+$/ // Forces digit after decimal point

    if (personalHours && regex.test(personalHours)) { // Run if input is not blank and passes RegEx
      if (response.d.results[0].__metadata.etag.replace(/"/g, "") == $("td .ms-descriptiontext")[0].innerText.replace("Version: ", "").split('.')[0]) {
        // Run if item's data from REST matches version shown in form
        addChildItem(id, title, personalHours, actualHours)
      }
    }
  });
  return true; // firing before request above begins
}
```

The function is returning as true before running the jQuery AJAX call which runs `addChildItem()` that manipulates fields within the form and posts relevant data to a separate list.

```
function addChildItem(id, title, personalHours, actualHours) {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://example.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ChildList')/items",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      __metadata: {
        'type': 'SP.Data.ChildListListItem'
      },
      ParentID: id,
      Title: title,
      HoursWorked: personalHours
    }),
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log("success", data);
      var actualHoursNum = Number(actualHours);
      var personalHoursNum = Number(personalHours);
      $("input[title$='Actual Hours']").val(actualHoursNum + personalHoursNum);
      $("input[title$='Personal Hours']").val('');
      // Input is getting cleared on save but shows previous number when form is opened again
    },
    error: function (data) {
      console.log("error", data);
    }
  });
}
```

This is causing the form to accept the field value manipulations but only after the save and before the automatic closure of the form.

I need `PreSaveAction()` to wait until after `addChildItem()` is successful to return `true` but I'm not sure how to do this. I have tried using a global variable named `returnedStatus` that gets updated when `addChildItem()` is successful but the return value in `PreSaveAction()` still gets looked at before the jQuery AJAX call is ran.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `I need PreSaveAction() to wait until after addChildItem() is successful to return true` You can't. You would need to use async logic to achieve this. I'd suggest looking in to callbacks (as your AJAX logic already uses) or create your own promise and return that, then the calling logic can execute whatever is needed when the promise resolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a similar case by setting `async: false` to add user to group in PreSaveAction.

[Original thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/ac93c698-a2ab-4955-b1c1-48f1776b97e4/fetch-clientside-people-picker-multi-user-values-and-insert-into-custom-sp-group-programmatically?forum=onlineservicessharepoint#fe22e762-bad8-41d8-a5a4-778c806134cd)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function PreSaveAction() {
            var check = false;
            var controlName = 'MultiUsers';
            // Get the people picker object from the page.
            var peoplePickerDiv = $("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='" + controlName + "']");
            var peoplePickerEditor = peoplePickerDiv.find("[title='" + controlName + "']");
            var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerDiv[0].id];            
            if (!peoplePicker.IsEmpty()) {
                if (peoplePicker.HasInputError) return false; // if any error
                else if (!peoplePicker.HasResolvedUsers()) return false; // if any invalid users
                else if (peoplePicker.TotalUserCount > 0) {
                    // Get information about all users.
                    var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();                                     
                    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                        console.log(users[i].Key);
                        var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups(22)/users";
                        $.ajax({
                            url: requestUri,
                            type: "POST",
                            async: false,
                            data: JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' }, 'LoginName': '' + users[i].Key + '' }),
                            headers: {
                                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                console.log('User Added');
                                check = true;
                            },
                            error: function (error) {
                                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                                check = false;
                            }
                        });                                                
                    }                    
                }
            } else {
                console.log('No user');
            }
            return check;
        }                
    </script>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly when I applied it to the GET and POST requests. Thank you.